# FastReport.Mono fails to export reports to PDF due to fonts issues

Tags: linux, fonts, mono, centos7, fastreport

I'm trying FastReport.Mono on Linux (CentOS 7) to see if I can make an app to generate reports from FastReport files. Example FastReport.Mono app seems to work, however there are problems with PDF export demo. I get the error message on attempt to export:

> Could not find file "/root/.local/share/FastReport/font.list".
>   File name: '/root/.local/share/FastReport/font.list'

The path `/root/.local/share/FastReport/` exists, but there's indeed no requested file inside.

I have installed truetype fonts mentioned in FastReport.Mono readme (they went into `usr\share\fonts\msttcore`), it did not change anything.

Creating an empty `font.list` file brought this error message:

> Enumeration has either not started or has already finished.

---

How do I resolve this problem and make PDF export work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could not find file "/root/.local/share/FastReport/font.list". File name: '/root/.local/share/FastReport/font.list'

BTW, you are working as root - this is not good for security. Anyway, you have to check following directory: "/usr/share/fonts/truetype". Does it exist and TrueType fonts are there? If not, then you can define shell variable FONTDIR with following command:

$ export FONTDIR="/path/to/truetype/fonts"

At the time of first export to PDF format the FastReport.Mono check fonts in this directory and build font.list file. If font.list file present in "$HOME/.local/share/FastReport/" directory, then software checks that information in this file is an actual.

> How do I resolve this problem and make PDF export work?

These issues should be fixes in next build.